# SystemMemoryOutofException-Elasticsearch IndexMany

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Im getting this error while indexing documents as an attachment. What can be the reason for this type of error. And why is it behaving differently when I run on server and when I run from visual studio.

More details about the problem is mentioned here.

Please have a look at the below link.

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/systemmemoryoutofexception-thrown-while-indexing-files-as-an-attachment/50916

TIA

Comment: What happens if you make the call directly from HttpWebRequest (without nest)?  I assume the out of memory is out of .net memory making the call or receiving the response and not an issue with elasticsearch server. Try using the .net profiler to see where the memory is overflowing and fiddler to check the calls getting passed to the elasticsearch server.

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft Documents are of different sizes. The biggest file right now I'm indexing would be less than 5mb size. Yesterday I was able to index 56mb of file. But today I'm not sure why this is happening. I have also attached the error in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

I am not confident on where the actual error is ocurring. You need to determine if the error is in .net (on the client side) or in elastic? Both Visual Studio and elasticsearch will get to a point where they break without enough memory (or allocated memory) on the host machine.

If it is in elastic (check the logs - or run in console mode) - [increase the heap space](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html).

If it is on the client, try [forcing your application in to 64 bit mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184681.aspx).